# How to solve problem with empty docker-entrypoint-initdb.d? (PostgresQL + Docker)

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Here is a part of my project structure:

[image]

Here is a part of my docker-compose.yml file:
[image: docker-compose.yml]

Here is my Dockerfile (which is inside postgres-passport folder):
[image: dockerfile]

I have init.sql script which should create user, database and tables (user and db are the same as in docker-compose.yml file)

But when I look into my docker-entrypoint-initdb.d folder it is empty (there is no init.sql file). I use this command:

> docker exec latest_postgres-passport_1 ls -l
>   docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

On my server (Ubuntu) I see:
[image: empty folder]

**I need your help, what am I doing wrong?** (how can I copy a folder with init.sql script. Postgres tell me that

> /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring
>   /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

(as he can't find this folder)

**All code in text format below:**

Full docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  redis_data: {}
  proxy_certs: {}
  nsq_data: {}
  postgres_passport_data: {}
  storage_data: {}

services:

  # ####################################################################################################################
  # Http services
  # ####################################################################################################################
  back-passport:
    image: ${REGISTRY_BASE_URL}/backend:${TAG}
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 9000
    depends_on:
      - postgres-passport
      - redis
      - nsq
    environment:
      ACCESS_LOG: ${ACCESS_LOG}
      AFTER_CONFIRM_BASE_URL: ${AFTER_CONFIRM_BASE_URL}
      CONFIRM_BASE_URL: ${CONFIRM_BASE_URL}
      COOKIE_DOMAIN: ${COOKIE_DOMAIN}
      COOKIE_SECURE: ${COOKIE_SECURE}
      DEBUG: ${DEBUG}
      POSTGRES_URL: ${POSTGRES_URL_PASSPORT}
      NSQ_ADDR: ${NSQ_ADDR}
      REDIS_URL: ${REDIS_URL}
      SIGNING_KEY: ${SIGNING_KEY}
    command: "passport"

  # ####################################################################################################################
  # Background services
  # ####################################################################################################################
  back-email:
    image: ${REGISTRY_BASE_URL}/backend:${TAG}
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - nsqlookup
    environment:
      DEFAULT_FROM: ${EMAIL_DEFAULT_FROM}
      NSQLOOKUP_ADDR: ${NSQLOOKUP_ADDR}
      MAILGUN_DOMAIN: ${MAILGUN_DOMAIN}
      MAILGUN_API_KEY: ${MAILGUN_API_KEY}
      TEMPLATES_DIR: "/var/templates/email"
    command: "email"

  # ####################################################################################################################
  # Frontend apps
  # ####################################################################################################################
  front-passport:
    image: ${REGISTRY_BASE_URL}/frontend-passport:${TAG}
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 80

  # ####################################################################################################################
  # Reverse proxy
  # ####################################################################################################################
  proxy:
    image: ${REGISTRY_BASE_URL}/proxy:${TAG}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - "proxy_certs:/root/.caddy"
    environment:
      CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL: ${CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL}
      CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY: ${CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY}
  #      ACME_AGREE: 'true'

  # ####################################################################################################################
  # Services (database, event bus etc)
  # ####################################################################################################################
  postgres-passport:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - "./postgres-passport:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
      - "./data/postgres_passport_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_PASSPORT_DB}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_PASSPORT_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSPORT_PASSWORD}

  redis:
    image: redis
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 6379
    volumes:
      - "redis_data:/data"

  nsqlookup:
    image: nsqio/nsq:v1.1.0
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 4160
      - 4161
    command: /nsqlookupd

  nsq:
    image: nsqio/nsq:v1.1.0
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - nsqlookup
    expose:
      - 4150
      - 4151
    volumes:
      - "nsq_data:/data"
    command: /nsqd --lookupd-tcp-address=nsqlookup:4160 --data-path=/data

  # ####################################################################################################################
  # Ofelia cron job scheduler for docker
  # ####################################################################################################################
  scheduler:
    image: mcuadros/ofelia
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./etc/scheduler:/etc/ofelia"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:latest

COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Comment: Does `dockerfile` and `init.sql` are in same folder? If no then have you faced any issue while building the docker image at this step `COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`

Comment: init.sql and Dockerfile are not in the same folder. But I did not get any errors while building docker image.

Comment: I have thought that my Dockerfile is incorrect, but I can't find my error

Comment: Please provide complete docker-compose.yml file

Comment: @mchawre I have added

Comment: Neither `docker build` nor `docker-compose` understands PNG files...can you replace your images with the actual text of those files, so others can try running your setup and it will be searchable later?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for your message. I have added my files in text format

Comment: I think that I have error in my Dockerfile as I have postgres-passport folder on my server (which is empty). Please can you check it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `docker-compose.yml` file, you say in part:

```
postgres-passport:
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes:
    - "./postgres-passport:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
    - "./data/postgres_passport_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

So you're running the stock `postgres` image (the Dockerfile you show never gets called); and whatever's in your local `postgres-passport` directory, starting from the same directory as the `docker-compose.yml` file, appears as the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory inside the container.

In the directory tree you show, if you

```
cd deploy/latest
docker-compose up
```

The `./postgres-passport` is expected to be in the `deploy/latest` tree.  Since it's not actually there, Docker doesn't complain, but just creates it as an empty directory.

If you're just trying to inject this configuration file, using a volume is a reasonable way to do it; you don't need the Dockerfile.  However, you need to give the correct path to the directory you're trying to mount into the container.

```
postgres-passport:
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes:
    #  vvv Change this path vvv
    - "../../postgres-passport/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
    - "./data/postgres_passport_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

If you want to use that `Dockerfile` instead, you need to tell Docker Compose to build the custom image instead of using the standard one.  Since you're building the init file into the image, you don't also need a bind-mount of the same file.

```
postgres-passport:
  build: ../../postgres-passport
  volumes:
    # Only this one
    - "./data/postgres_passport_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

(You will also need to adjust the `COPY` statement to match the path layout; just copying the entire local `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory into the image is probably the most straightforward thing.)

Comment: Your answer has helped me) Thank you for spending time on my question and good luck!